# How to remove a dictionary resource reference from a TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, binding

I have this element:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textReplyMessageStyle}">
   <Run x:Name="answerMessage" Text="{Binding Message, Mode = OneWay, FallbackValue = ''}" />
</TextBlock>
```

And I have the need to print in *answerMessage* either the content of the var Message (thanks to the binding) or an element from the dictionary (thanks to resource reference done by the code below).

```
answerMessage.SetResourceReference(Run.TextProperty, "Answer_Message_Not_Selected");
```

The binding is fully working as well as the dictionary reference, but after setting the resource reference once I can not find a way to make the binding work again.

I tried to re-do the binding programmatically but is not working...
The only working workaround I found is to set programmatically the text of *answerMessage*.
How can I remove the resource reference from the Run element and make the binding work again?

Just to give a bit of context the variable *Message* contains a number and the resource *Answer_Message_Not_Selected*
contains the text "*Not selected*" or a translation in a different language depending on the dictionary active on the program. I have to use dynamic resource reference because the language of the program can be changed on the fly.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your code for the binding re-do that is not working?

Comment: When you SetResourceReference on the Run element, you break the Binding you set in xaml for it. Rebinding sounds correct, so if it didn't work you need to look in debug output to see if there was a binding error. Another question is why do you change the value of the run itself, instead of changing the value it is binded to in the ViewModel?

Comment: @JasonTyler @o_w I managed to fix it, it was the binding indeed. The was an error in the way I was reminding the component.   


`Binding b = new Binding();
 b.Path = new PropertyPath("Message");
 b.Source = this;
 BindingOperations.SetBinding(answerMessage, Run.TextProperty, b);`

Comment: @o_w You made a really good point there. This is not a clean solution. Instead of setting the ResourceReference I tried to link the content of Answer_Message_Not_Selected to pre-binded Message obj via this:
`Message =Application.Current.Resources["Answer_Message_Not_Selected "].ToString()`
But this is not dynamic and I can not find a way to create a hypothetical "OnAnswerMessageResourceChange" event that can update the Message.

Comment: I will create another ticket for this to avoid confusion. Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial suspicions were correct, thanks to @Jason Tyler @o_w for confirming that.
When you set a reference to a Run (and also for similar elements) you lose the binding property.
The solution to my problem is simply to do the binding again.

```
Binding b = new Binding(); 
b.Path = new PropertyPath("Message"); 
b.Source = this;  
BindingOperations.SetBinding(answerMessage, Run.TextProperty, b);
```

This solution fixes the problem, but it is possible to fix the cause by setting the Answer_Message_Not_Selected resource to the bonded Message element.

```
Message = Application.Current.Resources["Answer_Message_Not_Selected "].ToString()
```

If the resource is dynamic, like in my case, you will need some sort of OnChange event observing the resource (or dictionary) to keep the content of Message always updated.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to work this around is to make the output of the `TextBlock` depends mainly on the `Message` property.

For example, you can bind the value of `Text` to `Message` only if the value of `Message` is not null, otherwise set it to your resource:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textReplyMessageStyle}">
    <Run x:Name="answerMessage" >
        <Run.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Run}">
                
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Message, Mode = OneWay, FallbackValue = ''}" />
                
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Message}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{StaticResource Answer_Message_Not_Selected}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Run.Style>
    </Run>  
</TextBlock>
```

Notice that you should set the starting value of `Text` inside the style because properties set in the control initializer will override any style setters!

Another thing you can do instead of setting the value of `Message` to `null` is to add a property `AnswerMessageSelected` in the view model, to be more explicit when the `TextBlock` should change its target value:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textReplyMessageStyle}">
    <Run x:Name="answerMessage" >
        <Run.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Run}">
                
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Message, Mode = OneWay, FallbackValue = ''}" />
                
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AnswerMessageSelected}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{StaticResource Answer_Message_Not_Selected}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Run.Style>
    </Run>  
</TextBlock>
```

And generally after using this method, it might not be necessary to use `x:Name` to refer to in the code behind, since it's a better practice to let the ViewModel do all the work and not the code behind the View:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource textReplyMessageStyle}">

            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Message, Mode = OneWay, FallbackValue = ''}" />

            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AnswerMessageSelected}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{StaticResource Answer_Message_Not_Selected}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, really nice and clean solution. 
Unfortunately, I can not use it in my case because that TextBlock object is used inside a bigger user control that is used under different scenarios that require various type of Answer_Message_Not_Selected messages.

Comment: @xSanciopanzax What about changing `{StaticResource Answer_Message_Not_Selected}` to `{DynamicResource Answer_Message_Not_Selected}`, I ran into the same problem before when I wanted to change colors but at the same time having the default color set to the active color mode (dark or light) dictionary